# Rust lifetimes with async/await

Tags: rust, async-await, borrow-checker, lifetime-scoping

The following code works without an async keyword on the function. After changing it to async what should I do to make it work.

```
use cgmath::Vector2;
use winit::window::Window;

struct A<'a> {
    a: Option<&'a Vector2<f32>>,
}

impl A<'_> {
    async fn new(b: &Window) -> A<'_> {
        Self {
            a: None
        }
    }
}
```

Compile errors

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:7:9
9  |       async fn new(b: &Window) -> A<'_> {
   |                       -           ----- return type `impl std::future::Future<Output = lang::A<'_>>` contains a lifetime `'1`
   |                       |
   |                       let's call the lifetime of this reference `'2`
10 | /         Self {
11 | |             a: None
12 | |         }
   | |_________^ associated function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'2` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`
```

I tried to change it to

```
struct A<'a> {
    a: Option<&'a Vector2<f32>>,
}

impl<'a> A<'a> {
    async fn new(b: &'a Window) -> A<'a> {
        Self {
            a: None
        }
    }
}
```

But it borrows the window for too long, and can not move the window after the call. Before I added a lifetime parameter 'a to struct A, it worked.

```
46 |       let mut a = A::new(&window).await;
   |                          ------- borrow of `window` occurs here
47 |       //player.init();
48 |       event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
   |       -              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move out of `window` occurs here
   |  _____|
   | |
49 | |         match event {
50 | |             Event::WindowEvent {
51 | |                 ref event,
52 | |                 window_id,
53 | |             } if window_id == window.id() => if !player.input(event) { // UPDATED!
   | |                               ------ move occurs due to use in closure
...  |
92 | |         }
93 | |     });
   | |______- argument requires that `window` is borrowed for `'static`
```

Comment: [It doesn't work for normal function as well](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1745ac6d0713b0e4b6a4d76324045c53).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to go, b: &Window doesn't need the same lifetime as A.a.

```
struct A<'a> {
    a: Option<&'a Vector2<f32>>,
}

impl<'a> A<'a> {
    async fn new(b: &Window) -> A<'a> {
        Self {
            a: None
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say `Self`, you say "`A` in the `impl` header". It contains a lifetime. Let's call it `'b`:

```rust
impl<'b> A<'b> {
    async fn new<'a>(b: &'a Window) -> A<'a> {
        A::<'b> {
            a: None
        }
    }
}
```

See the mismatch? You were supposed to return `A<'a>`, but you return `A<'b>`!

The fix is simple: either use `Self` for the return type too, or just use `A` for the return expression:

```rust
impl A<'_> {
    async fn new(b: &Window) -> A<'_> {
        A {
            a: None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: there is a subtle difference between using `Self` or `A`/`A<'_>` for the expression and return type. The latter will create `A` with a lifetime bound to `b` due to elision rules, while the former will not. [playground demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0a66cc8be893a47d96b743e9700f237e)